# Not working I/O method

Tags: java, file-io, io

I'm pretty new to JAVA, so I do not really see what I am doing wrong within the following method:

```
public void writeWNDFile(){
        String strFilePath = "C:/Users/fperrone/Desktop/ddd.txt";
        try
        {
          //create FileOutputStream object
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);

           DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
           dos.writeDouble(12);            
           dos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
        }
    }
```

The file is actually generated, but I don't get `12` as printed and expected result, but `@(`, which probably is the ASCII representation.

May you shed some light?

**EDIT**

Does eventually exist a `JAVA` function behaving similarly to the `MATLAB` `fwrite` function? I actually wanna write a binary file. In `MATLAB` I am simply calling:

```
fwrite(filename, A, precision)
```

How could I achieve the same in `JAVA`?

Comment: Use `PrintStream` instead of `DataOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

from [writeDouble java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeDouble%28double%29):

> Converts the double argument to a long using the doubleToLongBits
>   method in class Double, and then writes that long value to the
>   underlying output stream as an 8-byte quantity, high byte first.

As DataOutputStream uses the binary format to write, hence you are seeing the same. But you need to worry if you are going to read the file again using DataInputStream and readDouble method. It should give you the right values.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot He *has* explained it. What part of 'the binary format' don't you understand?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot So your comment is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

`DataOutputStream.writeDouble` and other methods of `DataOutputStream` are designed to write numbers in binary format. If you want your data be saved in text format use `FileWriter` and its `write(String)` method. You can convert `double` to `String` with `Double.toString(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
  //    new OuputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(strFilePath) /*, "UTF-8"*/)));
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(strFilePath /*, "UTF-8"*/);
  out.println(12);
  out.close();
```

Add the encoding, here UTF-8, when you want the application to write with the same encoding everywhere. Otherwise the default platform encoding is used.

[PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)'s `println` adds a newline, `print` not.